# Reading Service Ip's from outside property file using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

*I am using Angularjs for front-end development here i am generating different wars for dev,QA,Prod.Now for that reason i need to externalize my service ip's outside so i can just change my ip's based on environment without creating multiple wars.*

```
I used ng-constant as temporary fix.
app.constant('domain','http://523.143.438.43:8080');

How can i read this service ip from outside property file. so just by changing the ip externally we can make it QA,Prod.

Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: use JavaScript variable for this

Comment: can u please explain more